# ContinueWith / ContinueWithOnMainThread Breaks When Invoking an Action in Unity C#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever using ContinueWithOnMainThread, it seems my actions will not invoke and all code after it fails to run. There are no errors and I only found this by Debug Logging after each new line.

For example - onCompleted here is never called:

```
private void Blah(Action<Task, List<ItemData>> onCompleted = null)
{
    List<ItemData> foundItemsData = new List<ItemData>();
    CollectionReference charactersRef = db.Collection(charactersPath);
    charactersRef.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
        foreach (DocumentSnapshot document in snapshot.Documents)
        {
            Debug.Log("This will run.");
            onCompleted?.Invoke(task, foundItemsData);
            Debug.Log("This will not run.");
        }
    });
}
```

How can I get around or solve this?

**EDIT**: I found a way around it, even though I still do not understand what is going on here internally. I assume is has to do something with the way actions work with tasks.

First create this script:

```
public static class DelayUtility
{
    public static void Invoke(this MonoBehaviour mb, Action f, float delay)
    {
        mb.StartCoroutine(InvokeRoutine(f, delay));
    }
 
    private static IEnumerator InvokeRoutine(System.Action f, float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        f();
    }
}
```

Now wrap the onCompleted code as seen as above:

```
    this.Invoke(() =>
    {
        onCompleted?.Invoke(task, foundItemsData);
    }, 0.01f);
```

The number here delays the action by a small bit of time which allows for the code to run. This value can lower or higher than this.

Comment: You should show GetSnapshotAsync, also are the debugs printing?

Comment: Sounds like a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) to me you somehow worked around but that's for sure not a solution ;) I guess we would need a bit more context / [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It seems reproducible for me even in a blank project. Debug logs are not printed, nothing after the code works. To get a fore sure working example do the code in the question and create a new class of anything that is marked as [System.Serializable]. I don't know what it is but I agree some sort of a race condition is occurring with actions and tasks. What baffles me is that there is no error.